# Installed Specflow.Allure and met MSB4018:"The generateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, specflow, allure

I tried to use allure for my specflow test framework. I installed the latest Specflow.Allure Nuget package(3.1.0.6) and Specflow.NUnit (3.4.8). And then I tried to config the App.config as the official website lists. When I build the project, I met this problem. I am not quite sure what has happened. Here is my   github [repository](https://github.com/wujenny15/TestDemo)
.Can someone please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the error message, you can see the complete error message:
[image]

The configuration you have in the `app.config` is incorrect for SpecFlow3.

This is your current app.config content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
    </configSections>
    <specFlow>
        <plugins>
            <add name="SpecFlow.Allure" type="Runtime" />
            <add name="SpecFlow.NUnit" />
            
        </plugins>
        <stepAssemblies>
            <stepAssembly assembly="SpecFlow.Allure.SpecFlowPlugin" />
        </stepAssemblies>
         For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config 
         use unit test provider SpecRun+NUnit or SpecRun+MsTest for being able to execute the tests with SpecRun and another provider 
        <unitTestProvider name="SpecFlow.NUnit" />
    </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

You don't need anything of it.

1. Plugins
   Plugins aren't configured anymore in the app.config/specflow.json. We are searching for all files that end with `SpecFlowPlugin.dll` in the output folder.
2. unitTestProvider
   This option is also gone with SpecFlow 3. This is configured with runtime plugins now.

The resulting content for app.config is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
    </configSections>
    <specFlow>
       <stepAssemblies>
            <stepAssembly assembly="SpecFlow.Allure.SpecFlowPlugin" />
       </stepAssemblies>
    </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

So nothing is anymore configured because the default values work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas.  I already solved this problem by deleting the whole app. Config files. You are right, we don't need it even the Allure documentation says config the app.Config files. To use Specflow.Allure with Specflow, we need to specify the specflow.json files, just like the official website and remember to copy to the output. Check the allure documentation, Specflow.Plugin.Nuget.Test to see how we to use the binding to generate allure Specflow reports.

Another question is I don't quite understand why we need to include the specflow.json for allure in the project. What does it mean?

Comment: You can configure Allure in the specflow.json. See https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp#links

Comment: While checking Allure, I noticed they have some hooks in the plugin so you have to add it as stepAssembly to your config. I adjusted the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the Specflow latest version has some defects. If I update my specflow NuGet packages to the latest version and use it with Specflow.Allure, it occurs TypeInitializationException. But if I use specflow 3.3.57, the TypeInitializationException will disappear. Please see my Github repo to reproduce the error.
[TypeInitializationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjQ2q.png) [Valid Specflow Nuget Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K63vi.png)

Comment: SpecFlow.Allure is not yet adjusted to SpecFlow 3.4. Here is the GitHub issue for that: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/issues/133 You have to use SpecFlow 3.3 that it works.